# Gridview has Empty TH/TD After Initialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_Stores" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="True" AllowSorting="false" HTMLEncoded="false" AutoGenerateColumns="true" DataSourceID="myDataSource" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"/>...
```

Always regardless of the source/connection/autogenerated or not the first row in the body header or item template always contains a blank `<tr><th scope="col">` or `<tr><td>`;  it doesn't end nor does it terminate.  I cannot find a way to remove.

```
  protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
  {
    string ptn = "$#,###;<span style='color:rgb(255,0,0);'>($#,###)</span>;-";
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
    {
      SalesTotal += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "sales"));
      RentalTotal += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "rental"));
      PartsTotal += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "parts"));
      ServiceTotal += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "service"));
      OverallTotal += Convert.ToInt32(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "total"));
    }
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer) 
    {
      Literal TtalSales = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("TtalSales");
      TtalSales.Text = SalesTotal.ToString(ptn);
      Literal TtalRental = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("TtalRental");
      TtalRental.Text = RentalTotal.ToString(ptn);
      Literal TtalParts = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("TtalParts");
      TtalParts.Text = PartsTotal.ToString(ptn);
      Literal TtalService = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("TtalService");
      TtalService.Text = ServiceTotal.ToString(ptn);
      Literal TtalTotal = (Literal)e.Row.FindControl("TtalTotal");
      TtalTotal.Text = OverallTotal.ToString(ptn);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could manually define the header columns:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_Stores" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="True" AllowSorting="false" HTMLEncoded="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="myDataSource" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sales Total" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Rental Total" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Parts Total" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Service Total" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Overall Total" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of being able to bind the data columns directly.  However, it doesn't help the issue.  Turns out that on each template the gridview is adding a '<tr><th/td>' (not closed and not set from code to do so).

Comment: I see.. i didn't see the part about the <tr>/<th> not closing, my bad

Comment: Very interesting... i could see how that could be very damn annoying

Comment: Not only annoying but, fails when adding jquery libraries like jquery.datatable.  Without a solution it causes headaches and the display of which is horrific table html.